# two android projects sharing the same proguard process

Tags: java, android, proguard

I am developing two android projects A and B, and they both rely on a third lib-project C. 
When I compile A with proguard, A will be proguarded together with C. And when I compile B, B will be proguarded with C too.
And here comes the problem. Lib C are totally different in app A and app B after the proguard process because of the proguard optimization. 
My question is, how can I make lib C to be the same after proguard process in both A and B?

1. Lib C must be proguarded. So the keep option won't help.
2. A and B must be optimized.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. When you build an app with a library as part of the project, the result is just a single apk file. Why does it matter that you use the same library for two different apk files?

Comment: @Squonk Thank you for your reply. The reason is a long story. I want the library to be the same because the B.apk are not used to be installed. I want to delete the same library classes in B.apk and then try to load classes and resources of B.apk in A.apk dynamically.